# Getting CallSID for Twilio Softphone / Twilio.js incoming/outgoing calls

Tags: voip, twilio

I have created an application using https://www.twilio.com/docs/howto/twilio-client-browser-soft-phone as the template.  I am trying to log the CallSid for incoming and outgoing calls so that I can tag calls locally and use the Callsid to link between my local data and twilio's call store.  I am able to get the CallSid for incoming calls easily with:

```
Twilio.Device.incoming(function (conn) {
   if (confirm('Accept incoming call from ' + conn.parameters.From + '?')){
      connection=conn;
      conn.accept();
      callsid = connection.parameters.CallSid;
   }
   else {
      connection=conn;
      conn.reject();
   }
});
```

However, I can't seem to get it from any outgoing call initiated by the softphone.  I have tried here:

```
$("#call").click(function() {
   params = { "tocall" : $('#tocall').val()};
   connection = Twilio.Device.connect(params);
   callsid = connection.parameters.CallSid;
});
```

and here:

```
Twilio.Device.connect(function (conn) {
   $('#status').text("Successfully established call");
   toggleCallStatus();
   callsid = connection.parameters.CallSid;
   // And also tried
  callsid = conn.parameters.CallSid;
});
```

However, both of these return undefined.  I saw on https://www.twilio.com/docs/client/connection that the CallSid is set in the Outgoing .parameters towards the bottom of the page, so I assume it should be available in one of these function calls.

Is the CallSid available for calls originated by the client?  And if so, where/how do I access it?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the connection.parameters you are getting is empty and you can check this by plugging
console.dir(connection)

However, the reason is :
Twilio does not populate parameters on outgoing connections for twilio.js  V: 1.1 only for incoming connection
so please use twilio.js 1.2 to make it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Using TwilioJS 1.2 as recommended by adnanonline is the correct option. This version sets all appropriate parameters for you to access.

```
//static.twilio.com/libs/twiliojs/1.2/twilio.min.js
```