# Get Active callSid with JQuery for Call Transfering

Tags: jquery, twilio

I am building a web phone application and I am having trouble setting up an active call transfer function.  I can't seem to figure out how to get the callSid for my particular application.  When I use `conn.parameters.CallSid` it returns undefined.  The only way that I can think of to obtain the CallSid would be to have the voice url that set up POST to a database and use an ajax call to retreive that, but that seems overly excessive and I know there must be a straight forward way.

Here is the code I'm working with:

```
Twilio.Device.setup("<?php echo $twilioObj->token->generateToken();?>");
            var connection=null;
            Twilio.Device.ready(function (device) {
                $('#status').text('Ready to start call');
            });
            Twilio.Device.incoming(function (conn) {
                if (confirm('Accept incoming call from ' + conn.parameters.From + '?')){
                    connection=conn;
                    conn.accept();
                }
            });
            Twilio.Device.offline(function (device) {
                $('#status').text('Offline');
            });
            Twilio.Device.error(function (error) {
                $('#status').text(error.message);
            });
            Twilio.Device.connect(function (conn) {
                $('#status').text("Successfully established call");
                toggleCallStatus();
                console.log(conn.parameters.CallSid);
            });
            Twilio.Device.disconnect(function (conn) {
                $('#status').text("Call ended");
                toggleCallStatus();
            });
            function toggleCallStatus(){
                $('#call').toggle();
                $('#hangup').toggle();
                $('#dialpad').toggle();
            }
            $.each(['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','star','pound'], function(index, value) { 
                $('#button' + value).click(function(){ 
                    if(connection) {
                        if (value=='star')
                            connection.sendDigits('*')
                            else if (value=='pound')
                                connection.sendDigits('#')
                                else
                                    connection.sendDigits(value)
                                    return false;
                    }
                });
            });
        });
        function call() {
            // get the phone number to connect the call to
            var value=$.trim($("#tocall").val());
            if( value== false){
                params = {"tocall": "queue"};
                Twilio.Device.connect(params);
            }else{
                params = {"tocall": $("#tocall").val()};
                Twilio.Device.connect(params);
            }

        }
        function hangup() {
            Twilio.Device.disconnectAll();
        }
        function transfer() {
            // get the phone number to connect the call to
        }
        function sms() {
            params = {'tosms': $('#tosms').val(), 'sms': $('input[name=smsRadio]:checked', '#smsRadios').val()};
            $.post( "twilioApps/sms", params );
        }
        function conference() {
            // get the phone number to connect the call to
            params = {"toconference": $("#toconference").val()};
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having the exact same issue and I found the answer in this post: [Getting CallSID for Twilio Softphone / Twilio.js incoming/outgoing calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24020033/getting-callsid-for-twilio-softphone-twilio-js-incoming-outgoing-calls)

It seems that javascript Twilio Client version 1.1 does not populate parameters for outgoing calls. Using 1.2 version will fix the issue.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @NateBarbettini I agree with you that is better to leave a digested explanation of the answer. Links to referencing other StackOverflow questions can become invalid?

Comment: The above is the boilerplate text that is added when you flag an answer as link-only. Link-only answers aren't the worst problem by far, but it's something that we typically try to avoid. True, it's unlikely that another SO answer will suffer from link rot, but in general the policy here is that either the question is a straight duplicate, or the answer should be available here. It's not always 100% straightforward to figure out which applies; there's a little bit of grey. (Welcome to Stack Overflow, btw!)

Comment: @NateBarbettini Thank you very much! I'll try to improve my future answers having your advice into account.